# Selenium, C#: second click().perform() cancels the first

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

ENV
Selenium 3.141
C#
Chrome webdriver

I want to select an item in a "selection mode" where if I click on a up-left point and down-right point around the item, I get a square around the item and the item gets selected.

This is my code:

```
IWebElement item = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@title='item_to_select']"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.MoveToElement(item, 100, 100).Click().Perform();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
actions.MoveToElement(item, -100, -100).Click().Perform();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

When debugging and stepping over every line, I find that Selenium performs the first click, then when it gets to the second, it somehow loses the first click, and then clicks on the second point. I tried to "trick" it by adding another
actions.MoveToElement(item, 400, 400).Click().Perform();
and I got the item selected, but the code failed.

Any idea of why it does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

I solved creating multiple Action elements.

```
Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);

action1 .MoveToElement(item, 100, 100).Click().Perform();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
action2 .MoveToElement(item, -100, -100).Click().Perform();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Click the checkmark (V) to accept your own answer, then people can see its solved.